# Will Cedar Hedge pruned in dead zone grow back?

Tags: pruning, hedge, cedar

I decided to prune hedge. Will it grow new leaves.

[image: Old over-pruned hedge]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the cypress hedge will put out new growth from the brown branches, based on many observations.

As the dead parts become confirmed, you can trim the dead bits off.

Also maybe start growing something at the base to cover it.

Comment: Thanks! The lighter toned leaves are the new growth. Some of the info online indicates that Thuja does regrow. It does so very slowly.

Comment: https://www.hedginguk.com/thuja-hedging-conifers/

Comment: Thuja doesn't regrow much, if at all, from dead trunks - the only needled conifer that does is yew. You might see a few tufts of green after a year or three, but that would be about it. You will not get new growth substantial enough to cover the "legs", unfortunately,